# List of LM Integrated Circuits?

Tags: integrated-circuit, lm317, lm386, lm335, lm3915

Does anyone have / know of a list of all the LM integrated circuit packages available? The EE stockroom at my university recently reorganized and they cataloged several pages of part numbers without any descriptions of what they do. I was hoping to write a script to match them up. Also I need a part that I only know the description of, but am not sure if there is a LM part that does it so this is also for my personal interest.

I've checked out Texas Instrument's parametric search on their site, but it allows for everything except what I need. I was hoping to find something like [Wikipedia's 7400 series list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_7400_series_integrated_circuits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you the Discret circuit diagram of LM311[image]

and a link of LM integrated circuits list
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LM-series_integrated_circuits

Comment: That wiki page was started a few months after I originally asked this question. It looks like it's come a long way since then. It's really awesome that a group of people took the time  to put that together.

Answer (score 3):

As you probably know, the LM prefix was for [National Semiconductor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Semiconductor), who had acquired [Fairchild Semiconductor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairchild_Semiconductor) previously (who used various [prefixes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Practical_Electronics/Manufacturers_Prefix) it seems, see comments), and who were in turn acquired by TI (Fairchild are now a [separate company](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/) again though, so it may be worth searching their site).
I couldn't find a list as such (you may have to mail TI/Fairchild for something like this, or delve deep within their sites) but there is this page on decoding Nat Semi chip markings that may be of some use to you:

[NSC Device Marking Conventions](http://www.chipdocs.com/manufacturers/NSC.html)

Also this on ChipDB:

[Nat Semi DB](http://www.chipdb.org/cat-national-semiconductor-516.htm) (Check for Fairchild also)

Page 61 onwards [here](http://www.chipdocs.com/pnsearch/search.html?okwd=LM????&keyword=LM????&offset=1220) looks like a promising list also.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure LM was native to Nat Semi, Fairchild had their own designations  - uA (since my mu-symbol is hiding!) for linear as in uA741, and before the takeover, NatSemi equivalents were available at the same time, marked LM741 etc. I can't remember Fairchild's digital markings offhand.

Comment: You're right, I added that in in an edit but forgot to change the prefix, I'll edit it now, thanks. They did develop the uA702 and uA709 (Widlar) plus the ever lasting uA741, however, interestingly [this list](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Practical_Electronics/Manufacturers_Prefix) shows them using many other prefixes and doesn't include uA (it says Philips, TI and Motorola used it) They obviously did use it, but maybe only for a few parts (I'm not old enough to remember :-) )

Comment: The Chipdocs link looks like it will work for my purposes. Thanks for that. Maybe mailing the company would be the best option, although they're more likely to send me a hardcopy catalog than a digital list (maybe they do that via PDF theese days?)